# Every letter that is typed call on fuction

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a code below that scores a password that is typed into the entry box. I want to make the `score` command be called every time a letter is typed into the entry box but it is not working but it is not returning any error. Can someone help me?

```
from tkinter import *
import re

def showPassword(entry_box):
    entry_box.config(show = '')

def hidePassword(entry_box):
    entry_box.config(show = '*')

def addScore(l):
    global score
    for i in l:
        if len(i) > 0:
            score += 5
            
def minusScore(l):
    global score
    for i in l:
        if len(i) == len(password.get()):
            score -= 5
    
def Scoring():
    text = passwordText.get()
    if len(text) > 24 or len(text) < 8:
        l.config(text = 'Length of password must be between 8 and 24')
    else:
        a = re.findall("[^a-zA-Z0-9!\"£$%^&*()_+-=]", text)
        if len(a) != 0:
            l.config(text = 'Invalid character has been used.\nPlease see bottom right.')
        else:
            global score
            score = len(text)
            lowercase = re.findall("[a-z]", text)
            uppercase = re.findall("[A-Z]", text)
            digits = re.findall("[0-9]", text)
            specialCharacters = re.findall("[!$%^&*()-_=+]", text)
            addScore([lowercase, uppercase, digits, specialCharacters])
            if score - len(text) == 20:
                score += 15
            minusScore([lowercase, uppercase, digits])
            pattern = ['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m']
            pattern_freq = []
            for i in pattern:
                ind = pattern.index(i)
                if ind != 0 and ind != 25:
                    curr = pattern[ind-1]+i+pattern[ind+1]
                    pattern_freq.append(re.findall(curr, text.lower()))
            print(pattern_freq)
            for i in pattern_freq:
                for a in i:
                    score -= 5
                    print('Minus 5 patten')
            slider.set(score)
            if score > 20:
                l.config(text = 'Strong password')
                    
root = Tk()
root.title('Password generator')
passwordText = StringVar()
passwordText.trace("w", callback = lambda name, index, mode: Scoring)
password = Entry(root, show = '*', textvariable = passwordText)
lab = Label(root, text = 'Password:')
password.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 2)
lab.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 2, pady = 2)
generate = Button(root, text = 'Generate password')
slider = Scale(root, from_ = -120, to = 60, orient = 'horizontal', length = 150)
slider.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 3)
generate.grid(row = 2, columnspan = 3, pady = 3)
l = Label(root, text = '')
l.grid(row = 3, columnspan = 3)
show = Button(root, text = 'Show')
show.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: showPassword(password))
show.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: hidePassword(password))
show.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 2)
info = Button(root, text = 'i')
```

Comment: Have you done any research? Methods for calling functions based on events are documented, and there are countless examples on the internet. It's not clear why you need our help when the question can be answered from available documentation.

Comment: Sorry I did not specify the problem I have edited my question.

Comment: You're trying to use `score` as the name for both a global variable and a function - that's certainly not going to work.

Comment: I have edited my answer but I tried it again and that does not seem to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your `lambda` function isn't calling the `Scoring` function. Personally, I don't see any reason to use a lambda. If you use it, you must make sure the lambda function calls your scoring function (eg: `Scoring()` vs `Scoring`)

```
passwordText.trace("w", callback = lambda name, index, mode: Scoring())
```

Or, just directly call the function. You'll need to make the function accept the arguments sent by the trace.

```
def Scoring(*args):
    ...
...
passwordText.trace("w", callback = Scoring)
```